# Mongodb with very high CPU rate

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

When I ran the following code and killed it immediately(that means to abnormally exit), the CPU rate of Mongodb would go extremely high(around 100%):

```
#-*- encoding:UTF-8 -*-

import threading
import time

import pymongo

single_conn = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017)

class SimpleExampleThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print single_conn['scrapy'].zhaodll.count(), self.getName()
        time.sleep(20)

for i in range(100):
    SimpleExampleThread().start()
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
696m  35m 6404 S 1181.7  0.1 391:45.31 mongod
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

My Mongodb version is 2.2.3. When the Mongodb worked well, ran the command "strace -c -p " for 1 minute giving the following output:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 33.50    0.322951         173      1867           nanosleep
 33.19    0.319950         730       438           recvfrom
 21.16    0.203969          16     12440           select
 12.13    0.116983       19497         6           restart_syscall
  0.02    0.000170           2        73           write
  0.00    0.000016           0       146           sendto
  0.00    0.000007           0        73           lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           open
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        87           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           pwrite
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           msync
  0.00    0.000000           0        29           mincore
  0.00    0.000000           0        73           fdatasync
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.964046                 15248           total
```

When the cpu rate of Mongodb went very high(around 100%), ran the same command giving the following output:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 29.12    5.064230        3088      1640           nanosleep
 28.83    5.013239       27851       180           recvfrom
 22.72    3.950399      658400         6           restart_syscall
 19.30    3.356491         327     10268           select
  0.02    0.004026          67        60           sendto
  0.01    0.001000         333         3           msync
  0.00    0.000269           9        30           write
  0.00    0.000125           4        30           fdatasync
  0.00    0.000031          10         3           open
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        30           lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        57           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           pwrite
  0.00    0.000000           0        14           mincore
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   17.389810                 12331           total
```

And if I run the command "lsof", there are many socks with the description "can't identify protocol". I don't know what goes wrong. Are there some bugs in Mongodb?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem? You started a bunch of (collection scan) queries in different threads and mongod got busy? Does this map to an actual problem beyond this toy script? What bug would you say this is? This is too vague to be a useful question. You also might try this with a more recent version, like 2.6...though I can't say what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: My application of Python used Mongodb to store data and there exist some sub-processes. Sometimes I needed to kill all the processes which would make processes to exit abnormally. And if I did it for a few times, the CPU rate of Mongodb would go extremely high. And the above things I post are the diagnosis I made. However, I still can not figure what is the cause. Is there something wrong in my code or  may be this just a bug of Mongodb. In my opinion, though my processes exit abnormally, the Mongodb should deal with it properly. However, this is not the case.

Comment: It's still not exactly clear what the problem is. CPU usage is high, which is not ipso facto a problem. How long does it stay high? Is it locking up other operations? What conclusion are you trying to support (but not stating explicitly) from the strace information? Is there anything in the mongod logs? How many connections do you have open to mongod when the abnormal shutdowns occur?

Comment: 1. After the CPU usage goes very high, it will stay at the high level until I explicitly kill it.
2. When the CPU usage is very high, any operations can be done. So, no locking up exists
3. I want to find when the CPU usage goes very high, which system call occupies the CPU for the longest time. But from the strace information, it seems during the same interval, the number of system calls of the two situation is about the same. The difference is the value of "usecs/call". While this value was small when Mongodb went well, it was very high when Mongodb went wrong. So, no conclusion can be draw.

Comment: 4. When I looked at the mongod logs, nothing special existed, just the normal log message, such as "connection accepted from" and "end connection"
5. The number of connections is not the key factor. Ten connections can also make the CPU usage go very high as long as sub-process(written in Python, did not call the function close() of pymongo) abnormally exits.
6. Besides, the db.serverStatus() showed that the global locking rate was really low, no deadlock existed.
Did you need more extra information? I am not very sure what information I should provide. Please beg my pardon.

Comment: I'm just still struggling to understand what the problem is. The CPU usage went high, presumably because mongod was doing something like terminating a connection or whatever, but you haven't talked about any bad effects of this, or if the duration of high cpu is long enough to be concerning. The fact that the cpu went high because mongod did something isn't a worthwhile cause for concern, honestly. What *bad* thing is happening?

Comment: The problem is CPU usage went high even though on operation was performed. And therefore the system was in a very heavy loaded state. I have to restart mongodb to let the CPU usage resume to the normal level. Yesterday after I regraded the mongodb to the newer version(2.6), this problem disappeared. I am sorry I might have wasted your time.

Comment: No, it's ok...if the cpu usage stays high for no reason that's a real problem. I just wasn't sure what the problem really was. I'm glad upgrading fixed it.